# Do pytorch detect overflow or underflow?

Tags: pytorch

Because deep neural net and RNN involve many times of multiplying, I guess, overflow or underflow would be frequent.

I'm just curious whether deep learning library detect overflow or underflow operation and show any warning message, or just ignore it.

Comment: do you mean vanishing/exploding gradients?

Comment: yes, exactly. oh after I heard that, I realized something.

Answer (score 0):

You can track issues related to vanishing/exploding gradients by tracking how your gradient changes over time. Although this approach is more tailored to
detecting exploding gradients, more so than vanishing gradients.

One way would be to look at the value of the largest gradient:

```
max(p.grad.detach().abs().max() for p in model.parameters() if p.grad is not None)
```

Or by looking at the norm of all stacked parameter (looking at it as a single tensor).

These are two approaches used by [`torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_.html) to determine whether the gradient needs to be clipped: here are the actual lines in the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/bce4c82f0d2e4d36b96e5e10314c3bae16ed705e/torch/nn/utils/clip_grad.py#L33).